# mongodb how to get current logged in user

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

I can successfully get all the users but what I need is to get the logged in user's detail. `.find()` find everyone in the DB is there a specific func to get the current user? I thought `User.getUser()` mongodb func would identify the currently logged in user but apparently not.

I'm creating a user profile page for this logged in user.

Login

```
module.exports.login = function (req, res){
 User.find(req.body, function (err, results){
    if (err) throw err;

    var jsonToken = {
        username: req.body.username,
        expiry: new Date().toISOString()
    }
    var encryptedData = btoa(JSON.stringify(jsonToken));
    console.log(encryptedData);

    if (results && results.length === 1){
        res.json(encryptedData);
    }

   })
}
```

Get user

```
module.exports.getuser = function (req, res) {
console.log('get current user detail');
User.find(req.body, function(err, result) {
    if(err) throw err;

    if(result) {
        console.log(result);
        res.json(result);
    }
})
}
```

Angular Ctrl

```
 var getUser = function() {
        signupService.getUserDetail()
            .then(function(response) {
                console.log(response.data);
            });
    }
```

Comment: use fineOne to get one user

Comment: Yeah I did that, but how can I get the user that is currently user who is logged in? I've added my getUser angular ctrl in my post above.

Comment: once authenticated save user id it in cookie with probably jwt or similar, for new request read that cookie and query with that user id

Comment: I'm storing the result I get from the exports.login but I'm only saving the username and save it in the localStorage. Can you show me how to do the querying?

Comment: this angular-fullstack generator has full implementation - https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack - has some implementation in this file - https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/blob/master/templates/app/server/auth(auth)/auth.service.js

Answer (score 2):

The [`db.runCommand`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) function and [`connectionStatus`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/connectionStatus/) command might be what you're looking for.

- `connectionStatus` - Returns information about the current connection, specifically the state of authenticated users and their available permissions.

### MongoDB Shell Example

```
> db.runCommand({connectionStatus: 1})
{
    "authInfo" : {
        "authenticatedUsers" : [
            {
                "user" : "myUser",
                "db" : "myDB"
            }
        ],
        "authenticatedUserRoles" : [
            {
                "role" : "dbAdmin",
                "db" : "myDB"
            },
            {
                "role" : "readWrite",
                "db" : "myDB"
            }
        ]
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```